# Does the MailChimp API provide capability of adding emails to its mail list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mailchimp

I need to integrate MailChimp into my Cordova project, and I found out that someone has done it in a website with MailChimp PHP wrapper: [how to add email address to mailchimp list using api call in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363065/how-to-add-email-address-to-mailchimp-list-using-api-call-in-php)

I have found that MailChimp provides API for NodeJS which I use often but am not familiar with: https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-node

Can I add email addresses into my MailChimp mail list with its API in Cordova Project?

Comment: The MailChimp API for Node that you linked is for their version 2 API, which is outdated, they are now on API V3.  You might look at this answer already posted on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425701/ajax-mailchimp-signup-form-integration?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX Mailchimp signup form integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425701/ajax-mailchimp-signup-form-integration)